# Android Volley POST request formatting issues

Tags: php, android, post, android-volley

I have an Android app that, once a button is pressed, sends a HTTPRequest to a .php file on my server. Inside the HTTPRequest I store POST variables that is processed server-side.

This is my code:

```
public void sendRequest(Context context, String url, final HashMap<String, String> hm) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    Log.w("url", url);

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.w("Response", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.w("Sending progress", "Failure");
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            return new JSONObject(hm).toString().getBytes();
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            return hm;
        }
    };

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(sr);
}
```

Note that the HashMap variable used is passed into the method itself because I want to use this method dynamically across different other classes. The data gets there okay, but with some glaring issues:

1) For some reason, my JSON String is transmitted as a "key" and not a "value". I actually asked a question about this just now - someone was kind enough to answer me - you can see the question at [POST data in PHP formatting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902334/post-data-in-php-formatting-issue). Is there a way to solve this?

2) Weirdly enough, when my data reached PHP, all " " and "." characters were replaced with "_". I suspect other sensitive characters would be the same, such as "/" and "'". I understand if this was a GET variable but should this still be happening for POST variables? Or is this related to (1)?

---EDIT---

The HashMap that I'm passing into the method `sendRequest` is dynamically generated, but in general it's just:

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("personName", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1).getText().toString().trim());
hm.put("personNumber", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2).getText().toString().trim());

sendRequest(getApplicationContext(), "http://foo.com/bar.php", hm);
```

The data gets there okay it's just formatted very weirdly and it does have an impact on my processing on the server-side.

Comment: show your hashmap you are passing to server

Comment: check this url : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52531318/7319704

Answer (score 0):

```
String  _Url= "put your url here";
//rest request
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, _Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if(response !=null)
        {
   //you can check the response here by puting log here
        }





    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("error", "error: "+error);



    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {



        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        params.put("key1", value in string);
        params.put("key2", value in string);

        params.put("method", "mehtod name here");


        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return params;
    }
};
            queue.add(sr);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, initialize RequestQueue in onCreate.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Then prepare you variables

```
Map<String, String> params= new HashMap<>(); 
params.put("key1", "arg1");
params.put("key2", "arg2");
params.put("key3", "arg3");
```

And with this void POST query to server-side code.

```
private void sendRequest(final String QUERY_URL, final Map<String,String> mapParams) 
    {

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, QUERY_URL ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) { 
                        //Log.d(TAG, response);  
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { 
                        //Log.d(TAG , error.toString());  
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                return mapParams;
            }
        };

        queue.add(postRequest);
    }
```

And

```
sendRequest("http://foo.com/bar.php", params)
```

Comment: But... what's the difference between your code and mine?

Comment: I use Map<String, String> instead of HashMap<String, String> due it's documentation.